# Issue with curl invoked via golang (exec.command) on Windows with XML parameter

Tags: xml, windows, go, ssl-certificate

I am using roughly this code.

```
    args = append(args, "-vvv")
    args = append(args, "--location")
    args = append(args, "https://example")
    args = append(args, "-E")
    args = append(args, "cert_dev.pem")
    args = append(args, "--key")
    args = append(args, "key_dev.pem")
    args = append(args, "--header")
    args = append(args, `'SOAPAction: http://example/RequestExample'`)
    args = append(args, "--header")
    args = append(args, `'Content-Type: text/xml'`)
    args = append(args, "--data")
    args = append(args, fmt.Sprintf(`'%s%s%s'`, pre, escapedText, pos))
    cmd := exec.Command(`curl`, args...)
    log.Println(cmd.String())
    output, err := cmd.Output()
```

The command run unsuccessfully via exec.Command but copy and pasting cmd.String() into a git bash console works as intended. The error when is run via exec.Command is  Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. which hints at an issue with the payload in --data. Some threads say that the BOM character is to blame but how is this if im not even using a file is just a fmt.Sprintf string with escaped text being generated with xml.EscapeText

Its kinda arcane to run a simple request via curl but the gist is that golang seems to not support ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 (at least after trying with code from other stackoverflow questions), which is the schema used by the other third party server, the output produced when running is something server specific which says that certificate is not being sent.

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cert_dev.pem", "
key_dev.pem")
if err != nil {
   log.Fatalf("server: loadkeys: %s", err)
}
///caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
//println("dfucl:", caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(capem))
config := tls.Config{
    Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{cert},
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    MinVersion:         tls.VersionTLS12,
    ///RootCAs:            caCertPool,
    ServerName: "example.com",
}

tr := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
tr.TLSClientConfig = &config
//tr.TLSClientConfig.Renegotiation
// tr.TLSClientConfig = getCerts()
// tr.TLSClientConfig.Certificates = []tls.Certificate{cert}
tr.TLSClientConfig.Renegotiation = tls.RenegotiateOnceAsClient
```

I suspected something is wrong with windows formating so i tried to run it with git bash, adding git bash as parameter with no success

Comment: you can read it https://github.com/golang/go/pull/51612, in `src/syscall/exec_windows.go` fucnttion `appendEscapeArg`, it will add `'` auto some time, see the return result  of function `EscapeArg` is good

Comment: Are you sure you want `--data` (which is for sending in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format) and not `--data-binary`?

Comment: As to `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384` — please ask on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts) as AFAIK no member of the Go dev team reads `go` tag here on SO.

Comment: Yes, i had tried with --data-binary

Comment: To anyone interested in the question about `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384`–[here](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/kcL_Hd4qyh4/m/XseKHbcMAQAJ) is the message.

Comment: As for ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 yes, its supported by golang but only with TLS 1.2